# Adding logo to shipping rates on checkout - WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am trying to add a little FedEx logo in front of shipping rates returned during checkout. I am able to log the text of the labels for shipping rates using below, but the image isn't being added.

```
function add_fexdex_logo(){
    ?>
    <script>
        var fedexEdit = jQuery('label[for=shipping_method_0_fedex13first_overnight]').text();
        console.log(fedexEdit); //this works
        fedexEdit.replace('FedEx', '<image src="https://www.example.com/fedexlogo.jpg" alt="fedex logo"></image>'); //this doesn't
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_order_total', 'add_fexdex_logo' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total', 'add_fexdex_logo' );
```

I assume it's got something to do with the Ajax in the checkout, so if there is a better hook or way of doing this that would be helpful to know.

Comment: Post the solution as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED:**

Never mind, I'm a dingus. I can't replace a string within .text() with an image. Below is the working version.

```
function add_fexdex_logo(){
    ?>
    <script>
        var fedexEdit = jQuery('label[for=shipping_method_0_fedex13first_overnight]');
        console.log(fedexEdit);
        fedexEdit.before('<image src="https://www.example.com/fedexlogo.jpg" alt="fedex logo"></image>');
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_order_total', 'add_fexdex_logo' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total', 'add_fexdex_logo' );
```